# Encoding/decoding fails on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, crypto++

I am looking for a bit of help with my encode/decode functions on cross platforms. Currently the code works across windows OS's but fails on linux. Currently it is untested on Mac.

```c++
void tradingDialog::on_SaveKeys_clicked()
{
    // Encryption properties store iv and password information
    EncryptionProperties props;

    // Generate a 256 bit random IV from 4 separate 64 bit numbers
    props.iv = crypto_random();
    props.iv2 = crypto_random();
    props.iv3 = crypto_random();
    props.iv4 = crypto_random();

    // What cipher function do we require?
    props.cipher = Algorithm::AES;

    // Qstring to string
    string password = ui->PasswordInput->text().toUtf8().constData();
    // the password used for encryption / decryption
    props.password = string(password);

    /*==========  The main cryptostreampp usage  ==========*/
    boost::filesystem::path pathAPI = GetDataDir() / "APIcache.txt";
    // Create a stream in output mode to create a brand new file called apicache.txt
    //CryptoStreamPP stream(pathAPI.string(), props, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    CryptoStreamPP stream(pathAPI.string(), props, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);

    // ------------------------------------------------------
    // NOTE:
    // After creating the stream, there will be a short pause
    // as the key stream is initialized. This accounts for
    // one million iterations of PBKDF2
    // ------------------------------------------------------

    // write to the stream as you would a normal fstream. Normally
    // you would write a buffer of char data. In this example,
    // we write a string which is basically the same thing.
    // Stream operator support to be properly added in future.

    // qstrings to utf8, add to byteArray and convert to const char for stream
    const QByteArray byteArray = (ui->ApiKeyInput->text().toUtf8() + ui->SecretKeyInput->text().toUtf8());
    const char *API = byteArray.constData();

    stream.write(API, 64);

    // make sure stream is flushed before closing it
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
}

void tradingDialog::on_LoadKeys_clicked()
{
    // Encryption properties store iv and password information
    EncryptionProperties props;

    // Generate a 256 bit random IV from 4 separate 64 bit numbers
    props.iv = crypto_random();
    props.iv2 = crypto_random();
    props.iv3 = crypto_random();
    props.iv4 = crypto_random();

    // What cipher function do we require?
    props.cipher = Algorithm::AES;

    // Qstring to string
    string password = ui->PasswordInput->text().toUtf8().constData();
    // the password used for encryption / decryption
    props.password = string(password);

    boost::filesystem::path pathAPI = GetDataDir() / "APIcache.txt";
    // Create a stream in input mode to open a file named APIcache.txt
    CryptoStreamPP stream(pathAPI.string(), props, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    // Read in a buffer of data
    {
        QString Key = "";
        stream.seekg(0);
        char buffer[33];
        stream.read(buffer, 32);
        buffer[32] = '\0';

        // Should print out "api key 32 digit"
        Key = buffer;
        ui->ApiKeyInput->setText(Key);
    }

    stream.flush();

    // now seek to digit 32 and read in api secret
    {
        QString Secret = "";
        stream.seekg(32);
        char buffer[33];
        stream.read(buffer, 32);
        buffer[32] = '\0';

        // Should print out "api secret 32 digit"
        Secret = buffer;
        ui->SecretKeyInput->setText(Secret);
    }

    stream.flush();
    stream.close();

}
```

When printing "password" and "API" in "on_SaveKeys_clicked()". Both are correct.

When printing "password" in "on_LoadKeys_clicked()" it is correct.

When printing "Key" in "on_LoadKeys_clicked()" it is incorrect.

When printing "Secret" in "on_LoadKeys_clicked()" it is incorrect.

CryptoStreamPP can be found at https://github.com/benhj/CryptoStreamPP/tree/master/cryptostreampp

Comment: You should probably explain what you mean by *"incorrect"* (we have no idea what  *"correct"* and  *"incorrect"* looks like) . Also, there's about 8 source files on the referenced GitHub. Since the problem is likely related to the GitHub files, can you provide the relevant information here? (I don't know where I should be looking in the GitHub source files, and I don't know what I should be looking for).

Comment: Firstly, I don't see any print statements anywhere in your code so the symptoms you describe make little sense. Also, you do know that the IV used to decrypt should be exactly the same as the IV used to encrypt, right? You ought to understand the example on the github page first and then put together a minimalistic -- and basic -- example yourself that forgoes any qstring stuff.